# Opening an PDF file locally on an angular app

Tags: angularjs, pdf

Anyone here can help me show the pdf file linked on a angular web app.

I read forums, they said make my url valid so that the app will trust the link that I posted or embeded on the html. But i can't seem to make it work, or even know what to do about their examples. I'm a beginner here so a step by step guide will help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [angularjs-pdf directive](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf). It's well documented on GitHub, and has a **demo** you can [check out here.](http://sayan.ee/angularjs-pdf/)

Comment: thanks for the response, however I solved it by just using the embed tag
embed(src='/pdf/helpGuide.pdf' type='application/pdf' class='helpPDF')
I'm using jade.

I really appreciate for your response.